# How do I exit node from my script?

Tags: node.js

In my script, I want to be able to quit node without doing it manually (CTRL-C), however process.exit() does not seem to work?

I tried a few different things but is this because I still have an active stream open? How would i go about closing all active streams?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
readline = require('readline');


var count = 0;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});


process.stdin.on('data', function(data){ 

  console.log(data);
  process.stdin.destroy();

})

rl.on('line', function(line){
  count++;
  rl.close();
})


function getBytes(data){
   return Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf8');
}




process.stdin.on('close', function(){
  console.log(getBytes(count));
  process.exit();
})
```

Comment: Can you show what gets logged to the console? Why are you calling `process.stdin.destroy()` from the `'data'` event handler (in general you shouldn't assume the size of `data` in a single `'data'` event handler call)? FWIW generally you should not need to forcefully exit the process. The best practice is to let it exit naturally by closing servers, network connections, etc.

Comment: The first log displays "<Buffer 6d 61 7a 65 6e 0a 70 6f 70 61 74 0a 6e 6f 64 65 0a 74 65 73 74>" and the second is just 21.

Comment: Also i am calling process.stdin.destroy() because otherwise my stdin.on('close') function doesn't get fired. What is the correct process?